# Keep values in Singleton instance synchronized

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using a singleton variable in my app called retrievedArray.

```
@interface Shared : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *books;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *books;

+ (id)sharedManager;

@end
```

This is accessed in multiple .m files using
NSMutableArray *retrievedArray; ...in the header file

```
retrievedArray = [[Shared sharedManager] books];
```

My question is how do I ensure that the values inside retrievedArray remain synchronized across all the classes.

Please let me know the exact code for doing this, as I have never handled such cases.

**I am using NSThread in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
retrievedArray = [[Shared sharedManager] books];
```

> My question is how do I ensure that
>   the values inside retrievedArray
>   remain synchronized across all the
>   classes.

It isn't clear what you are asking.   No matter how many times you call the `books` method, it will always return a reference to the same object;  the same array (assuming your singleton is implemented correctly).

I.e. this:

```
NSMutableArray *books1 = [[Shared sharedManager] books];
NSMutableArray *books2 = [[Shared sharedManager] books];
NSMutableArray *books3 = [[Shared sharedManager] books];
NSMutableArray *books4 = [[Shared sharedManager] books];
```

Produces 4 variables that all refer to *the same object*.  If you say `[books1 addObject: aBook];`, that is exactly the same as saying `[books2 addObject: aBook];`, etc...

The bigger question is one of the threading;  if you are thinking about having different references to the books array across different threads or queues, then you have a synchronization issue on your hands in that `NSMutableArray` is not thread safe.

Comment: yes, sorry for not being clear. I am using thread in my app and hence there seems to be some synchronization issue. How can i fix that ?

Comment: That is a very broad question... what specifically is the problem?  If it is the array, the way you fix it is by not accessing the array from multiple threads.  That could be done in any number of ways, but probably warrants a different question.

Comment: ok..Yes, it is a shared array. I'll open a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

Mike Ash wrote a post with examples about the [care and feeding of Singletons](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-10-02-care-and-feeding-of-singletons.html)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are making sure that `Shared` is always using the same instance of `books` (this is, it's value is allocated once and never replaced with another instance) everything is fine. If you modify the content of the mutable array everyone will notice, since all are referring the very same instance.